# How to save info in database when user favorites?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm failing to save the info to when a logged in user clicks on the favorite button.

This is my first week in javascript class(including ajax). We're allowed to copy paste as long as we understand the process. So the first thing I did was looking up tutorials as to how to make favorite / unfavorite buttons and took over a template. Then I searched up how save the info in the database once the user clicks the favorite button. I'm not sure linking to external websites is allowed but I specifically took over this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>New page name</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  /*
  * Create cookie with name and value.
  * In your case the value will be a json array.
  */
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = '',
    date = new Date();
    if (days) {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  /*
  * Read cookie by name.
  * In your case the return value will be a json array with list of pages saved.
  */
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + '=',
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i,
    cookie;
    for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i += 1) {
      cookie = allCookies[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(nameEQ.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  /*
  * Erase cookie with name.
  * You can also erase/delete the cookie with name.
  */
  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, '', -1);
  }
var faves = new Array();
  $(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; // current page url
    $(document.body).on('click','#addTofav',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageTitle = $(document).find("title").text();
      var fav = {'title':pageTitle,'url':url};
      faves.push(fav);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });
    $(document.body).on('click','.remove',function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      faves.splice(id,1);
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(faves);
      createCookie('favespages', stringified);
      location.reload();
    });

     var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));
     faves = myfaves;
    $.each(myfaves,function(index,value){
      var element = '<li class="'+index+'"><h4>'+value.title+'</h4> <a href="'+value.url+'">Open page</a>  '+
      '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove" data-id="'+index+'">Remove me</a>';
      $('#appendfavs').append(element);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addTofav">Add me to fav</a>

  <ul id="appendfavs">

  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays "add me to fav" like it's supposed to but then when I click on it, it returns:

```
(index):54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):54)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

The assignment is as follows:

""- Show a 'favorite' icon / heart. Make this clickable via jQuery / JavaScript. If you click on it, an AJAX request must be sent with the blog post id. A WP plugin must 'process' the AJAX request, and store in the session (or database) that user X has liked a certain blog post. The server must return a JSON response."

Now had a small side question, for after I resolve the error of this thread, is my way of thinking correct:

- Through CSS I'll create a heart button
- This script itself does the ajax request with post ID
- WP plugin I've done before
- This script provides the JSON response

Thank you stack overflow in advance, I look forward to learning!

Comment: Does it say in the assignment that you need to store anything in a cookie? If not, why add the extra complexity? It sounds like you can skip that step and just make an immediate request to an API which will store it in a database.

Comment: No it doesn't. Apologies I'm completely new to this. So while copy pasting is completely allowed I thought it would be best to find a template that saves it directly into the database, which I was sure this one in my post does.. Through basic PHP I know how to do the API request part but after that I'm lost on what you mean.

Comment: The `readCookie('favespages')` is returning `null` as there is nothing on the cookie at initial load of the app, Hence add a check to validate `readCookie` function or just return empty array instead of `null` from `readCookie` function to avoid this error.

Comment: Your PHP service will need to receive an API request, with the data about what to favorite. What your code is doing is inserting the information into a cookie, which isn't permanent. Its also only available on the front-end - your PHP server won't have access to anything you store this way. In order to make this code work, all you need to do is change "var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages'));" to "var myfaves = JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages')) ? JSON.parse(readCookie('favespages')) : [];", but understand that nothing is being stored in a database or in a permanent way.

Comment: Thank you both. @Joseph is there an easy way to save the data somewhere? Like in the database or a json file, keyword on it being simple, otherwise I’ll leave that out for now to avoid extra complexity like you said in your first post.

Comment: The way this would generally work is the client-side code (the code you posted) would only do the ajax call, not the storage itself. Here's an example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/7pdc6oz8/ - that JSFiddle has a very basic ajax call implemented. You'll need to fill in the details - I notice that you said you need to pass the blog post ID, which doesn't seem to be present anywhere in your code. Once the ajax request is made, your PHP server will need to store the information in whatever way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Joseph, it managed to do it with that and now it's functional! I had one last question: Do you have any idea why your code returns status 200? It's supposed to do that but in school we had to use ajax hooks before it would give status 200, without the hooks it wouldn't function. So It was as pleasant surprise to see this work straight away.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ajax hooks - do you mean a global hook that always happens after any ajax call receives a response, but before it calls the success method?